# Write not fully displayed Django field

Tags: django, django-models, django-custom-field

I need to write a Django custom field where the stored value is not fully displayed.
For example if the stored value is "079684" I need it to be displayed as "---84". Is it possible to do so ? If yes how should I implement my custom field ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is something to do at the *model* level. Typically the "presentation" of data is handled at the form, view, and/or template level.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by overriding from_db_value() of the custom field method.

Comment: It's an option, but I would say you should consider what can be achieved in a simple way.  Using normal CharField and than slicing the value in template would be in my opinion more simple than going with custom field.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your value as a string in your model and than use slice in template to show only last two character.

```
{{ value|slice:"-2:" }}
```